# Why I'm not getting complete div in BeautifulSoup python?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

My code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.quora.com/profile/Siddhartha-gaur-5"
r = requests.get(URL)
 
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,'html5lib')
for data in soup.find("div", id="root"): 
    print(data)
```

I am getting the blank div tag with no content as below.

`<div id="root"></div>`

What I want to extract all the content as given in this example :[Complete div......](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBxYX.png)

Comment: You should use selenium. it is loading dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code that work

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
# MAIN
driver = webdriver.Chrome('cromedriver path here')
driver.maximize_window()


#Go to link
URL = "https://www.quora.com/profile/Siddhartha-gaur-5"
driver.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'lxml')
driver.close()

for data in soup.find("div", id="root"): 
    print(data)
```

Comment: This code is working perfectly, but the problem is I want to host my script & with Web Drivers I'm facing problems is there any other way to do that?

Comment: Yes, there is also alternative way, create a new post that is api calls json response. I wanted to post my answer but your that post deleted

Comment: Ok I'm posting, Once again thanks for ur answer  :)